# Wrongly double saving a file in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

Hi_all!
I'm in trouble with my Windows 10 / MS Access 2013 data-bank - I'm writing a program to file (many replicate) radio amateur contacts that should be saved each new, in a new record...

The problem is that I have a 'Progressive Search (the one that dynamically searches at each new Call's letter is entered in a textbox)' and, when I'm showed that I have already worked that station, I mark the Call's station in the listbox and click "GetData" to get all the common data to a new Form to file to add some more fresh info. My Access is saving, in a new file! ONLY the letters I typed in the 'Progressive Search' and, afterwards, when I click the "INSERT" button, it saves in a subsequent file all the data I got from the last contact + the specific ones of the current contact!
This is the code...

just to illustrate:

[image]

```
Private Sub btnGetData_Click()          ' Btn   "GetData"
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Me.lstStaff.Value
    If Not rst.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    With Me.lstStaff
        If IsNull(.Value) Then .Value = .ItemData([ID])
        Me.Call.Value = .Column(1)
        Me.QRA.Value = .Column(2)
        Me.QTH.Value = .Column(3)
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub btnInsert_Click()       ' Btn   "INSERT"

    Dim SQL
    SQL = "INSERT INTO tblStaff (Call,QRA,QTH,RST,QRG,TimeStart,TimeEnd)" & _
    "VALUES (Call,QRA,QTH,RST,QRG,TimeStart,TimeEnd)" & "CurrentDb.Execute SQL"

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

What should be done to prevent the 'Search typed letters' to be saved... and in a separate file?

Comment: Your SQL string is a mess. You need to put in some literal data into the VALUES clause rather than listing names of controls. Set a break point in the insert logic and have a peek at the SQL statement you've built.

Comment: Why are you concatenating "CurrentDb.Execute SQL" to SQL string? If form is bound to tbStaff and you enter data into controls then also run SQL to save a record, will definitely get 'double saving'. However, you are declaring and building SQL string then don't do anything with it. I really don't see any code that would cause 'double saving'. If lstStaff is intended only to be a search tool, not a data input control, it must be UNBOUND.

Comment: And by 'new file' and 'subsequent file' do you really mean 'record'?

Comment: Nicomp, I thank you very much for your so kind comments, though, at the moment, I do not have the necessary technical level to implement your suggestions - once you didn't detailed the enclosed idea. I'm studying SQL language a lot and I'll have in mind your words; eventually, I'll thank you once more...   ;-)

Comment: Yes, June7; by 'file, n subsequent file' I mean 'rec, n subsequent rec'; thanks. lstStaff is intended to b just a search tool; but, the textbox 'Call' is both used to search (when I type: PY2, i.e.) n, afterwards, when I mark in the listbox the PY2UJJ n click the getData btn, it's used to port n insert the complete 'Call' data on the new rec. I tried already to separate the 'Search' from the 'Insert' instance, but I faced another problem; it saved just once, Ok, but on the prior ID-contact n not in a new ID-contact! What I need is to save the searched data + the new info in a new ID-contact.